# Publishing a message to queue in RabbitPy

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitpy

I am looking to RabbitPy for consuming and publishing messages. The consumption part is fine, However I want to send back messages to a specific queue after doing something with the inbound message. However I cannot find anyway to do this in the documentation.

https://rabbitpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/message.html

Here is my consume code:

```
with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
        with conn.channel() as channel:
            queue_read = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, QUEUE_NAME)
            queue_write = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, QUEUE_NAME_RESPONSE)
            # Exit on CTRL-C
            try:
                # Consume the message
                for body in queue_read:
                   # do something on inboud...
```

Here is what it seems I can only set in creating and sending a message:

```
message = rabbitpy.Message(channel, result)
message.publish(EXCHANGE, RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY, mandatory=False)
```

There is nothing related to a queue. How can I send a message to a specific queue with a routing key?

In Pika I would use the following:

```
channel = cnn.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=EXCHANGE, durable='True')
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=EXCHANGE, type='direct', durable='True')
channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME_RESPONSE, durable='True')
channel.queue_bind(exchange=EXCHANGE, queue=QUEUE_NAME_RESPONSE)
channel.basic_publish(exchange=EXCHANGE, routing_key=RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY, body=return_JSON,properties=pika.BasicProperties(content_type='text/plain', delivery_mode=2))
channel.close()
```

How can I do this with RabbitPy?

Answer (score 0):

using `EXCHANGE, RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY`  the queue is binded.

[image]

For example

We have 2 queue, Queue1 and Queue2. 1 exchange as Exchange and routingky as 
routingkey1 and routingkey2.

```
Exchange  + routingkey1  ==> Queue1 
Exchange  + routingkey1  ==> Queue2
```

Assume that w ehave the above binding.

When your publisher send a message using `Exchange  + routingkey1` it will be send to Queue 1.  If the publisher use `routingkey1` message will be sent to Queue2.

You can create the necessary binding using Rabbitmq Management UI or form your code. more details can be found [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html)

In Rabbitpy you can do something like this,

```
amqp = rabbitpy.AMQP(channel)
amqp.queue_bind(queue='Queuq1', exchange='Exchange', routing_key='RoutingKey1')
```

Comment: This is RabbitPy not Pika, I need to explicitly declare this in the code, not through the UX (we cannot do this). We can solve this issue with Pika but not with RabbitPy.

Comment: queue_bind(queue='', exchange='', routing_key='', nowait=False, arguments=None)   https://rabbitpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/amqp.html

Comment: @techdisrupt, Check the updated answer. Also remove Pike from your Tag.

Answer (score 0):

I possibly have this by binding the routing key to the exchange and the queue. I have the following:

```
queue_write.bind(EXCHANGE, routing_key=RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY, arguments=None)
```